# Prodigy - Using pattern file with model

Tags: spacy, prodigy

Can you add a pattern file to a model?

```
matcher = Matcher(nlp_lg.vocab)
pattern = [{"LOWER": "tumulus"}]
matcher.add("thing", [pattern])
MyText = df.loc[52]["TEXT"]
doc = nlp_lg(MyText )
spacy.displacy.render(doc, style='ent')
```

It seems to make no difference and doesn't tag 'tumulus'.

Output:

"(Name: SS 26271656 ORG ) Woolley Barrows PERSON ( NR ORG ). (SS 26191653 CARDINAL ) Tumulus (NR)."

Answer (score 1):

When you create a Matcher object, it has no special association with the pipeline, it's just an object that exists. Which is why it doesn't modify the pipeline output at all.

It sounds like what you want to do is add an EntityRuler - which is a component that wraps a Matcher - and have it overwrite entities. See [the rule-based matching docs](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#entityruler-usage) for an example of how to use the EntityRuler. It's a bit like this:

```
ruler = nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler")
patterns = [{"label": "ORG", "pattern": [{"LOWER": "tumulus"}]}]
ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
```

Note `nlp.add_pipe`, which is key because it actually adds the component to the pipeline.